# Some Unicode characters not displaying on Kindle

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, kindle

I am implementing a book for Kindle device using HTML, but some Unicode special characters are not displaying in Kindle, such as:

```
    X -hax: x&#772; 
    X-double bar : x&#x033F;
    R- hax : &#x035E;R
```

My head tag is :

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```

Please help me; how can I display the characters listed above (and shown below if your browser has sufficient Unicode support):

- ̿   U+033F COMBINING DOUBLE OVERLINE
- ͞   U+035E COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON
- ݲ          U+0772 ARABIC LETTER HAH WITH SMALL ARABIC LETTER TAH ABOVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might a be surprise, but not a single operating system includes fonts for every single Unicode code point.

Take Wikipedia's lead and embed images for unsupported glyphs.

A random example, the new [Kazakhstani tenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstani_tenge) currency symbol: ₸ vs. [image]

**edit:** It looks like there is little support for combining diacritics in PHP with GD/Freetype2 you have to look forward towards PHP6 or alternative method of producing them, such as [GD with Pango](http://mgdm.net/weblog/using-pango-for-php-a-taster):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34670

Comment: @Steave Can you please show me the embed images for above characters that i mentioned in question?

Comment: @Tushar as they are diacritics you will have to perform the combining yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a font issue, not an issue with your page.

Unfortunately, only standard languages are fully supported, even in Windows/Unix systems on laptops.

Comment: You mean only standard languages are supported in kindle..Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I mean, you have fonts, and each font have some set of characters which are provided. The standard is you have characters for Latin fonts, cyrylic (modern), greek, arabic, chinese, japanese... With thai, glagolic etc. - usually it's a problem. This is why PDF has font embedding. With HTML you can use only fonts on client device, so some of them may work for you and not for the others.

Comment: That's misleading: there are no "standard languages" that you can expect everywhere to work (except maybe for those that *only* use the basic ASCII set, which pretty much limits the list to English and even then you'll be unable to represent some less common words).

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpfull content on charter set on amazon kindle forum

Here is [link](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx3J34YF7P7GBYY)

Comment: "Our Discussion Boards feature has been discontinued."

Answer (score 0):

I found that combining doesn't work. Will show just about all Latin letter. I was showing what overstike looks like, so used the letter w with 2 vertical lines as looks like w with " on top, but it just shows as a normal w. With Kobo you can choose the Georgia font to show more letters, or add a font.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).